# Booking system app using MIT app inventor working but blocks allow for lower than 0 and above the maximum

Tags: android, app-inventor

I am creating an app using MIT app inventor, it's a simple computer system booking app that allows students to select a room and reserve a computer or cancel the reservation.
[image: Screenshot of my app.]

When the room is clicked, in this case room 10 the buttons appear and the computers available text is set to 10 computers. I have the code block below the same for all buttons.
[image: App inventor blocks.]

These buttons when clicked allow the user to click reserve (which removes one from the total of 10) or click cancel (which adds one to the total of computers.)
[image: code blocks for reserve and cancel]

Obviously the number of computers can't be less than 0 or more than 10 because 0 is a minimum and 10 is the maximum in each room,
[image: amount is -1]

[image: amount 11]

I need it so if cancel is clicked when the score is at 10 that it will stay as 10 and not go to 11 and if reserve is clicked at 0 the number can't go below 0.
[image: Error highlighted]

I know the error is there somewhere but in theory if number is less than 0 set to 0 and, if number is more than 10 set to 10 should work, what blocks do I need to add so that the number can't go below 0 or above 10? The code with the red box around it works to add and remove one when the button is clicked it's the code on the lines below that doesn't work.
[image: something isn't working.]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The less than and more than were the wrong way around (correct way now shown) I fixed this myself.
[image: corret way, they're shown in the way that works.]